# Perforce command line p4 move gives "file(s) not opened on this client" error

Tags: perforce

I need to rename a bunch of .hpp files to .h in a large project, so using the client is out of the question (unless there is a rename *.hpp *.h option I have not found yet).  So I have done this before on a different workspace and it worked fine.  I had an app create a batch file with all the move commands and hey presto, many files renamed.

I set everything with p4 set:

```
P4CLIENT=tyrel.vanniekerk_8.0.6 (set)
P4EDITOR=C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe (set)
P4PASSWD=******* (set)
P4PORT=ssl:servername:port (set)
P4USER=tyrel.vanniekerk (set)
P4_ssl:servername:port_CHARSET=none (set)
```

And ran the command:

```
p4 move "D:\Folder\Header.hpp" "D:\Folder\Header.h"
```

And get:

```
D:\Folder\Header.hpp - file(s) not opened on this client.
```

I renamed it in P4V and it ouput the exact same command.  I set my client to something else and got the error about the file not being in that client, so I think the client name is correct.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`p4 move` operates on files that are already open -- think of it as being a type of edit (but instead of editing the content, you're editing the name).  Hence:

```
p4 edit Header.hpp
p4 move Header.hpp Header.h
```

You can edit the content either before or after the `p4 move` command, and you can `p4 move` a file multiple times (if you move it back to its original name, it retains whatever content changes you made in the meantime).

The 2017.1 release has a `p4 move -r` command that behaves like `p4 edit` + `p4 move`.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks.  My guess is I had the entire branch checked out the last time I tried this.  I will just add in an edit command beforehand, it does not look like we have the most recent version of Perforce, but good to know for future reference.